# name-lookup in generic lambdas in intel icc

Tags: c++, c++14, icc, name-lookup, generic-lambda

What are the name-lookup rules in a generic lambdas, if in the surrounding scope names from a different namespace are imported?

```cpp
namespace ns
{
  template <class F>
  void bar2(F f) { f(0); }

  template <class F>
  void bar1(F f)
  {
    bar2(f);                // (1)
  }
}

void foo()
{
  using namespace ns; 
  bar1([&](auto i) {        // (2)
    // using namespace ns;  // (3)
    bar1([&](auto j) {});   // (4)
  }); 
}

int main()
{
  foo();
}
```

The situation above gives different results in `gcc` and intel `icc`. While in `gcc` it compiles without errors and warnings, in `icc`  I get the error message

```
error: identifier "bar1" is undefined
```

in line (4). See also https://godbolt.org/g/PYzWtw The situation changes if (1) is removed, or if in (3) the names from namespace `ns` are imported again, or if in (2) and (4) `auto` is replaced by `int`. Thus, small changes, that seem irrelevant, make the code compile in `icc`. In all cases, it compiles fine with `gcc`.

Is this a bug in intels compiler?

My compiler setup: gcc 6.3.0, intel icc 18.0.1. Also with clang 4 it compiles fine.

Since it works with non-generic lambdas, I assume, the problem is related to the instantiation point of the lambda `operator()`. But I don't get which compiler performs correctly.

Comment: I think I've just come across the same problem. Have you any update on this?

Comment: Also in icc 19 the error is not resolved. Since it compiles fine in all the other major compilers gcc, clang, msvc I assume this is just a problem if intel. It can be resolved by `using namespace ns` also inside the first lambda, so that the name `bar1` gets imported again.